# Setting Processor Affinity in C# doesn't work

Tags: c#, process

I am running a program on a windows server running in Amzon EC2 Cloud. The instance I am using has 32 virtual cores available. I want to show linear scalability of a system and thus need to control the amount of cores my system can work on. I am trying to do this using the `ProcessorAffinity` property of the `Process` class. Precisely, my code to set the affinitiy is the following:

```cs
void SetCPU(int numCPU)
{
    var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    Debug.Assert(numCpu <= Environment.ProcessorCount)
    var str = GetProcessorAffinityString(numCPU);
    var serverProcessorAffinity = Convert.ToInt64(str, 2);
    currentProcess.ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)serverProcessorAffinity;
}
//Produces output: numCpu=4 -> 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111
//...............: numCpu=8 -> 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
//...............: numCpu=16 -> 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 1111 1111
//...
static string GetProcessorAffinityString(int numCPU)
{
    var str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; i++)
    {
        if (i < numCPU) str += "1";
        else str += "0";
    }
    //Reverse
    char[] charArray = str.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(charArray);
    return new string(charArray);
}
```

However, when I run the program, no matter what input `numCpu` is, the process always uses 32 cores. I can manually change it in the Resource Manager as a workaround, but ideally I would like this to be done programmatically.

Does anybody have an idea what the problem with this code could be ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building and parsing some Int64 value (here I'm confused why you do it) try use simple bit mask for neccessary CPU number:

```
var cpuBitMask = 1 << (cpuNumber - 1);
```

Bit mask idea taken from original MSDN documentation for [`Process.ProcessorAffinity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.processoraffinity?view=net-7.0)

Here `cpuNumber` is `int` value, which represents CPU (core) number (*non zero-based*).

To simplify usage, you can create an extension method to set `ProcessorAffinity`:

```
public static class ProcessExtensions
{
    public static void SetProcessorAffinity(this Process process, int cpuNumber)
    {
        if (process is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(process));
        if (cpuNumber <= 0 || cpuNumber > Environment.ProcessorCount)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("CPU number must be greater than 0 and less than total CPUs amount");

        var cpuBitMask = 1 << (cpuNumber - 1);
        process.ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)cpuBitMask;
    }
}
```

And, ofc, usage sample (Console application):

```
public static void Main()
{
    using var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    var timer = new Stopwatch();

    for (var cpuNumber = 1; cpuNumber <= Environment.ProcessorCount; cpuNumber++)
    {
        currentProcess.SetProcessAffinity(cpuNumber);
        Console.WriteLine($"Running single-CPU test for 10 seconds on CPU #{cpuNumber}...");

        // Primitive CPU (core) loadout for 10 seconds
        timer.Start();
        while (timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < 10) { }
        timer.Reset();
    }
 
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Tested on 4C/8T CPU (`Environment.ProcessorCount` returns 8) - each of 8 "CPUs" was fully loaded one by one for 10 sec, which was displayed in Task Manager's CPU performance tab.

---

## **UPD:**

If you want to use not single, but specified amount of CPUs, you may try create bit mask using bitwise OR operation with assignment:

```
var cpuBitMask = 1; // At least 1 CPU used
for (var i = 2; i <= cpuAmount; i++)
     cpuBitMask |= 1 << (i - 1); // using bitwise OR assignment for each additional CPU you planning to use
```

Extending previous example, add another extension method, which now will accept not a number of concrete CPU, but amount of total CPUs you want to use for associated `Process` instance:

```
public static class ProcessExtensions
{
    // public static void SetProcessorAffinity(this Process process, int cpuNumber) { ... }
   
    public static void SetProcessorAffinities(this Process process, int cpuAmount)
    {
        // Same validation logic...
        if (process is null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(process));
        if (cpuAmount <= 0 || cpuAmount > Environment.ProcessorCount)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("CPUs amount must be greater than 0 and less than total CPUs amount"); // ..except text correction

        // Initializing bit mask with at least 1 CPU
        var cpuBitMask = 1;
        // and using bitwise OR for each additional CPU
        for (var i = 2; i <= cpuAmount; i++)
            cpuBitMask |= 1 << (i - 1);

        process.ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)cpuBitMask;
    }
}
```

And also updated usage example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    // Specify amount of CPUs (cores) you wish
    var amountOfCPUs = 3; 

    using var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    currentProcess.SetProcessorAffinities(amountOfCPUs);

    var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    while (timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds < 15) { }
    timer.Reset();
}
```

Tested this on another 4C/4T CPU - works as expected (loaded 3 of 4 CPUs (cores), 4th chills).

*P.S. I'm very new to this kind of stuff and just do a little research both for myself new experience and yours. Because of that i can't guarantee that I provide correct example. I basically depend on my own tests, which results with expected behaviour. If you find a better way or solution or can improve my suggestion - feel yourself free.*

*P.P.S. also, I assume that updated example, which uses certain amount of CPUs, will still use them in order they is. So if you have, for example, 8C/8T CPU, and providing 6 to SetProcessorAffinities, it will use first 6 cores, but not from 2nd to 8th or from 1st to 7th. I don't find any info about this. Maybe it is impossible, or maybe it need much deeper code with some PInvoke's to native Windows libraries, which I can't provide.*

Comment: Thx for the answer. I don't want to use a single cpu at a time though, but rather a bunch of cpu's. In my code I create the bitmask from a string. Putting the number of 1's in the string and then interpreting that string as a base of 2 into a Int64.  You are shifting the 1 n-1 times which gives you access to exactly one core through the mask. If I want to use 4 cores simultaneously I believe that the mask should be 1111 = 0x000F. That's why my method adds 1's in the string. Could you expand your answer towards multi cpu usage ? Thx

Comment: Updated answer. Please check for yourself